# Copy Docker container from boot2docker under OS X

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I have boot2docker running on OS X 10.10.

I used docker to install `conceptnet5`, a 50GB big database that takes days to download from my location.

Now, somebody requested an Ubuntu VM with conceptnet5 running on it in a docker container from me.

So, to avoid downloading everything again, I wondered if there is a way to transfer conceptnet5's container from boot2docker to my newly created ubuntu vm.

[Here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/rspeer/conceptnet-web/tags/manage/) is the docker container I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also work with `save` and `load` command.

The `save` command will produces a tarred repository of the image. It will contains all parent layers, and all tags.

```
$ docker save myimage -o myimage.tar
# Or even better, gzip it using unix pipes
$ docker save myimage | gzip > myimage.tar.gz
```

Now you have a tarball with all the layer and metadata that you can pass around, offline, with usb keys & stuff.

To load it back, it's the `load` command. The load command will work with the following compression algorithm : `gzip`, `bzip2` and `xz`.

```
$ docker load -i myimage.tar.gz
# or with pipes
$ docker load < myimage.tar.gz
```

It's a little bit easier than running a private registry, but both works well.

Comment: Ultimately this was the easiest way to do it. Thanks alot!

Comment: No problem, it is quite useful and something often overlooked when there is need for "private" image but with simple needs (or for demo without internet access the use cases I faced :D).

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a [private docker registry](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry) and then [push](https://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/) the image there. Hopefully this private registry is on your local network so you should get much higher throughput. Then you can pull down the pushed image in your new Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I managed to get a private docker registry running on my host. But now my problem is that I can't seem to find it on my vm. It doesn't either show up on my host, wenn I try requesting resources with HTTP. Any tips?

Comment: What command did you use to launch it? You should expose the port using the -p switch and look for it at that port on your docker host.